# Geoserver Geowebcache clear layer with parameters tile cache with Rest API

Tags: geoserver, geowebcache

I'm using this command to clear tile cache of a certain layer:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<truncateLayer><layerName>my-layer</layerName></truncateLayer>"  "https://xxx.xxx.com/geoserver/gwc/rest/masstruncate"
```

This is working fine. But layer 'my-layer' is a parametrized layer (Viewparams). Is there a possibility to truncate only tiles with certain parameters?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I know this is possible using the /seed endpoint by providing parameter_viewparams to truncate by parameter...but it requires you do so one parameter at a time.